# Getting error message when trying to fetch access token from api.facebook.com/restserver.php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am following this github link :

https://github.com/minhkhoa2000/Facebook-Api/blob/master/gettoken.php

I want to get contents of this link in php when username and password are passed.
https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php

This link generates access token... When i try to fetch it from php it locks the account or shows invalid username or password. Even if correct Id password is passed to it. **What am i missing**?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Missing are details of your implementation... Except you, who could possibly know what you are missing? Have you provided username and password (as the error message suggests it)?

Comment: Yes i have passed correct username and password. Still it shows that it is wrong.

Comment: That’s probably just outdated, I am not even sure if that Rest APi even still exists. Anyway, you should find something that is more up-to-date, this apparently isn’t.

Comment: I have seen someone working on it. So was trying the same. :)

Comment: It's still working, not outdated.

Comment: Have any idea about it?